# Onchange textbox auto checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

When i change the Second textbox the 1st Checkbox will check. I want is when a change the value of 2nd textbox the Second Checkbox is automatically checked.

**This is my HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbx" onchange="checkbox_changed()">
<input type="text" id="chbx" onChange="checkbox_changed()" value="Value1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chbx" onchange="checkbox_changed()">
<input type="text" id="chbx" onChange="checkbox_changed()" value="Value2">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx");

    function checkbox_changed() {
      checkbox.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

The Solution is like this. But i use textbox not a dropdown.
http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/g3UQG/

Answer (score 2):

You have four elements with the same ID.  IDs in HTML must be unique.

Comment: It may or it may not.  Until you fix the HTML and make it valid, you are wasting your time.  Make it valid then think of a solution to your problem in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Id of an element must be unique, so use class instead.

Ty

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chbx" />
<input type="text" class="chbx" value="Value1" />
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="chbx">
<input type="text" class="chbx" value="Value2" />
```

then

```
$('.chbx[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $(this).next().val('')
    }
})
$('.chbx[type="text"]').change(function () {
    $(this).prev().prop('checked', this.value != '')
}).change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/su4h4/)

Comment: You should provide in pure JavaScript way not in Jquery

Comment: @antindexer I think the question is tagged using jQuery and there is no mention about should not use jQuery

Comment: Sir i want to see the solution is when a change the value of second textbox the second checkbox is checked

Comment: @wewe did you check the fiddle, it seems to be happening

Comment: the answer is like this. but i use textbox not dropdown.
http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/g3UQG/

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes it is tagged in jQuery. However I do not have any idea does the publisher of question aware of it. You can judge by his code. Another thing is, read carefully before answering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is html for you:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbx" onchange="checkbox_changed()">
<input type="text" class="chk" onChange="checkbox_changed()" value="Value1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" onchange="checkbox_changed()">
<input type="text" class="chk" onChange="checkbox_changed()" value="Value2">
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       // when you check your chbx checkbox, other checkbox is checked too.
       $("#chbx").change(function(){
         $('.chk').prop('checked', true);
       });
    });
</script>
```